# Property panel gone

Tags: edit-mode

I dnt know what it's called. But it keeps disappearing. how can I bring it back and make necessary adjustments when I need to?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't! Once you start the next action, that panel is gone for good. That applies when you add an object as well as with certain operations such as bevelling. The only thing you can do is use Ctrl-Z to go back a step and start again.

Comment: it will disappear as soon as you'll do a new action, but you can still try F9

Comment: So suppose I bevel something, segment is 9, then I do something else. 5 minutes later I want to increase the segment into 12,  you say I cant do that in Blender?

Comment: yes, unless you use a Bevel modifier for example

Comment: wow! Thank you. never knew this.

Comment: @RussianBlue Using these tools in _Edit Mode_ is therefore often called "destructive" modelling, since it usually changes the mesh irreversible (apart from undoing the action) or at least it's much more complicated to get back to the previous mesh. Using modifiers for beveling, subdividing etc. is a "non-destructive" way to model. The advantage is of course easy adjusting settings later in the process among other things. Disadvantage is that you have no real geometry to change manually in cases where you might want to do that. Then you need to apply the modifier > destructive.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I cant express my gratitude enough for letting me know this, Thank you.